# How to compare two custom ps custom objects and change the value of one based on the result of another?

Tags: powershell, object, psobject

Currently I have two sql queries that I have outputting the following columns

```
$A | Select-Object -Property DatabaseUserName, Role, PermissionType, PermissionState, ObjectType, ObjectName, col
```

AND

```
$B | Select-Object -Property DatabaseUserName, sysadmin
```

What I want to do in psuedo code: WHERE $B.DatabaseUserName = $A.DatabaseUserName THEN $A.col = $B.sysadmin. Currently I have it setup the following way:

```
$allUsers = $A | % {
        New-Object psobject -Property @{
            DatabaseUserName = $_.DatabaseUserName
            Role = $_.Role
            PermissionType = $_.PermissionType
            PermissionState = $_.PermissionState
            ObjectType = $_.ObjectType
            ObjectName = $_.ObjectName
            col = 0
        }
    }

    $allUsers += $B | Where-Object {$_.DatabaseUserName -like $B.DatabaseUserName} | % {
        New-Object psobject -Property @{
            $_.col = $B.sysadmin

        }
    }
```

This still leaves all the columns to be 0 from what I can see when I want them to actually be the value of $B.sysadmin. I am not sure if this is the correct approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Where-Object clause doesn't make much sense. What it says is "Where a property of one instance of array B is like the entire array of properties". -like is used to compare stings. -contains for arrays...but that wouldn't fix your code either....

If I understand what you're asking in your pseudocode, you want to assign a property of `$B` to a different property of `$A` when the `DatabaseUserName` property matches.  However the code you posted assigns an object to `$allusers` for each element in `$A`.  I am going to assume you want to update the objects in the `$allusers` array rather than in the `$A` directly.  To do that, try this:

```
Foreach ($au in $allusers) {
    $au.col = ($B | ? {$_.DatabaseUserName -eq $au.DatabaseUserName}).col
}
```

The above code loops through each item in `$allusers` and sets the `.col` property.  Note, this code works only if you have one and only one instance of `$B` which meets your criteria.  If you have 0, `.col` could equal `$null` or blank.  If you have more than one which meets the criteria, then your `.col` value would be an array.

Comment: This looks like a good start. So the the return values are the users in every database on a server. This means its possible for their to be more than one user in the DatabaseUserName, but I would still like to have a 1 even for repeated users. When I made changes and ran this their was no output in col (Using $allUsers | Out-GridView)

Comment: Check to be sure that the elements of $B.Col have the value(s) you expect.  Then change the assignment statement `$au.col =` to a `Write-Host` and see what it is finding inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out by doing a nested for each like so

```
    $AllUsers = $svrInfo | % {
        New-Object psobject -Property @{
            DatabaseUserName = $_.DatabaseUserName
            Role = $_.Role
            PermissionType = $_.PermissionType
            PermissionState = $_.PermissionState
            ObjectType = $_.ObjectType
            ObjectName = $_.ObjectName
            col = 0


        }
    }
    foreach ($admin in $sysAdmin)
    {
        foreach ($User in $AllUsers)
        {   
            if($User.DatabaseUserName -contains $admin.DatabaseUserName)
            {
                Write-Host("$User.DatabaseUserName matches $admin.DatabaseUserName")        
                $User.col = 1

            }



        }
    }
```